# Is there a way to filter featured questions based on "competence"?

Tags: support, bounties, filtering, my-tags

Being an SO addict and a reputation junkie, I'd like to see a list of questions that fall into my competence* and have an open bounty. Is there any way to achieve that?

`*` = Question matching some of my tags, or questions that would be shown under the "interesting" tab

Partial solutions are also welcome, like filtering bounty questions only based on my tags.

Comment: I don't understand. You have favorite tags and the "featured" tab. What more are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like to have both combined in a single view. Featured questions having my tags. Questions having an open bounty, but only those that have at least one of my tags. I thought the question is pretty clear - maybe I need to rephrase it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a bit of an hack and the special properties bountied/featured questions have.

This search will do the trick in 99% of the cases:

> [`intags:mine closed:no lastactive:7d.. hasnotice:1 locked:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+hasnotice%3A1+closed%3Ano+lastactive%3A7d..+locked%3Ano)

Let's dissect what is going on here:

- intags:mine *returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite.*
- closed:no *returns only questions that are not closed*
- lastactive:7d.. *for posts active in a specified time period*
- hasnotice:1 *returns only posts with a notice shown below them*
- locked:0 *returns only posts that are not locked*

Why does this work?
Questions that have a bounty on them can't be closed, bounties can only run for 7 days so they need to have been active the last 7 days, and the maybe surprising trick: the bounty text is actually a so called post notice. Post notices can also be added when a post is locked so we rule out those keeping the questions with most likely bounty notices.

Now it is possible to have a question with a post notice, that is not locked and also not a bounty. That is why I said for 99% of the cases.  Your search might return a false positive now and then.

For info on the other advanced search terms see [the Help topic on searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Pure awesome. Btw this answer deserves the ultimate necromancer badge - I asked this more than 6 years ago, and now bam! here is the perfect solution.