# Allow filters for bounty lists?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

[image]

As you can tell, SO has quite a huge amount of bounties.

Can we get a filter option for bounties like these? So similar to shopping sites, we can have filters for highest bounty --> lowest bounty, date expiring, activity, views, etc.

Comment: I always switch to a tag when looking for bountied questions ...

Comment: @rene Not just tagged questions. What if you want to sort those 401 bountied questions by the rep amount?

Comment: The current bountied questions are spread among a dozen tags, Android 51, Java 34, JS 32, IOS 32, c# 27 ... I assume regular users only are sufficient in a couple of tags. Sorting through at max 51 questions for a tag doesn't seem much of a deal?

Comment: @rene I think one thing you're failing to grasp here is that people don't just sort through questions all based off of your criteria.  I search through bounties by bounty amount. Some others want to see bounties by the category (authoritative answer needed, not enough attention, canonical source requested). Some others want to see bounties by when they expire.   So while it may not seem like much of a deal to you, it can be a big deal to other people.

Comment: Other filtering request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89240/is-there-a-way-to-filter-featured-questions-based-on-competence

Comment: I'd like to have this functionality too.